# can't set max-height to blocquote cloned div

Tags: jquery, textarea

I get a textarea with a keyup function attached. When the user type something, I want this text to be rendered inside the blockquote tag. blockquote css is set to`white-space: pre-wrap;`. In this way it take into account the newline. The problem now is that blockquote doesn't care of max-height property(200px). If itype in the textarea enter key several times, blockquote height grows infinitely. Any help?

```
$('#post_body').keyup(function() {    
$('blockquote').find('span').text($(this).val());
```

Comment: Did you try setting the blockquote overflow-y to scroll?

Comment: Yes. But I don't want the scrollbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or:

1.- you let it grow infinitely,

2.-or you put scrollbars,

3.-or you hide what is higher than a height(You can use height, and then overflow hidden)